# Mouse pointer jittering

Tags: 14.04, xorg, touchpad, synaptics, aspire

I have Acer Aspire E11 (E3-112-C97Q) netbook with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on it. Sometimes the mouse pointer starts to "jitter" and jump here and there, which makes the system completely unusable. I believe this is not a hardware problem since it does not reproduce under Windows 8 installed on the same computer. The rebooting does not always solve the problem, which seems to appear randomly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing the touchpad in the BIOS to *simple* made the trick. So it will work as a clickpad but no jittering. Also there is no right buttom as well. Also when it was happening I used to push **Ctrl-F7** to disable it and enable it again so that the jittering stop.

After changing the touchpad to simple your xinput output should look like:

```
vicente at vicente-miniUbuntu in ~/Downloads $
→ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)] 
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYN1B7D:01 06CB:2991 UNKNOWN              id=11   [slave  pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

...

Check this [link](http://blog.mdda.net/oss/2014/11/16/acer-e11-es1-111-c3nt-linux/), in the comments they mention about your problem, apparently it is a hardware problem

Note that for the right click issue you can always trigger it by tapping with two fingers once.